# Explode columns having nested list in pyspark using dataframes

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've a datafram having below column:

```
[Row(
col_1=True, 
col_2=[Row(val1=70, val2=None, val3=u'35f81fd0')], 
col_3=[
    Row(scr=100, id=u'ae288', 
    i_rs=[
            Row(a=
                [Row(id=42, value=u'10'), Row(id=49, value=u'100')], 
                c_d=None, t_i=None, name=u'', pd=413, st=0, stamp=None, t_s=50
                ), 

            Row(a=
                [Row(id=42, value=u'100'), Row(id=49, value=u'10')], 
                c_d=None, t_i=None, name=u'Jfe', pd=411, st=0, stamp=None, t_s=20
                ), 

            Row(a=
                [
                     Row(id=453, value=u'1523430000'), 
                     Row(id=709, value=u'1523516400'), 
                     Row(id=964, value=u'45'), 
                     Row(id=220, value=u'45'), 
                     Row(id=476, value=u'0'), 
                     Row(id=736, value=u'm_U:2;m_O:33;'), 
                     Row(id=340, value=u'0')
                 ], 
                c_d=None, t_i=None, name=u'', pd=1, st=0, stamp=None, t_s=10)
            ], 
    name=None, re=1, t_s=70, te=1)]
)]
```

I want to transform the above column and explode into multiple columns something like below:

[image]

How can I achieve above output in pyspark.

Comment: [Check This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864389/how-can-i-create-a-spark-dataframe-from-a-nested-array-of-struct-element)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a Spark DataFrame from a nested array of struct element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864389/how-can-i-create-a-spark-dataframe-from-a-nested-array-of-struct-element)

Comment: But that is using scala.

Comment: [Don't post pictures of code/data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) and don't [repost the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53158307/how-to-perform-column-comparisons-in-pyspark-using-dataframe-which-include-neste) multiple times. Simplify your question into an [mcve] and you'll have more success in getting an answer.